# AIX cluster show swing filesystems

Tags: aix

I am working on applications on an AIX 6.1 two-node cluster, with an active and passive node. Is there a command that will show me which mount points / file systems are shared and 'swing' from one node to the other when the active node changes, and which mount points are truly local to each node and not shared?

I can run commands with superuser access, but obviously I do not want to change/break anything, this is a production environment.